# Highcharts triangle (or any type of marker pointer) in stacked bars

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using the highcharts (for Angular 6) stacked columns/bars and I want to achieve something like shown in the following image:

[image: stacked bars]

The thing that I couldn't realize how can be obtained are the triangular markers.

P.S. The image shows dummy data that I found on the Internet.

Comment: this looks like two charts combined;  one to draw each of the bars, the second a series chart without a line, with each point marker being a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily using [Highcharts.SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) that provide direct access to the Highcharts rendering layer in order to draw primitive shapes. An existing chart's renderer can be accessed through Highcharts.Chart.renderer. Check the demo and code posted below.

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
          series = chart.series[0],
          trWidth = 5,
          trHeight = 8,
          used = [
            48,
            33,
            83,
            62
          ],
          svgText,
          svgArrow,
          text,
          yText,
          xText,
          yTr,
          xTr;

        if (chart.customSvgElems) {
          chart.customSvgElems.forEach(function(elem) {
            elem.destroy();
          });
        }

        chart.customSvgElems = [];

        series.data.forEach(function(serie, i) {
          text = used[i] + '% used';
          xText = serie.barX + serie.pointWidth / 2 + chart.plotTop + 3;
          yText = chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth / 2;
          svgText = chart.renderer
            .text(text, yText, xText)
            .add()
            .toFront();

          yTr = yAxis.toPixels(used[i]);
          xTr = serie.barX + serie.pointWidth + chart.plotTop;

          svgArrow = chart.renderer
            .path([
              'M', yTr, xTr,
              'L', yTr + trWidth, xTr + trHeight,
              'L', yTr - trWidth, xTr + trHeight,
              'z'
            ])
            .attr({
              fill: 'red',
              stroke: 'black',
              'stroke-width': 1
            })
            .add()
            .toFront();

          chart.customSvgElems.push(svgText);
          chart.customSvgElems.push(svgArrow);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Basic demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ac2zk6h/1/ 
Angular demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/y3kk252p41